# KeyError occures while opening the JSON txt file and setting it up into a DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, twitter, keyerror

I had a code, which gave me an empty DataFrame with no saved tweets. 
I tried to debug it by putting `print(line)` under the for line in json file: and `json_data = json.loads(line)`. 
That resulted a `KeyError`. 
How do I fix it? 
Thank you.

```
list_df = list()
# read the .txt file, line by line, and append the json data in each line to the list
with open('tweet_json.txt', 'r') as json_file:
    for line in json_file:
        print(line)
        json_data = json.loads(line)
        print(line)
        tweet_id = json_data['tweet_id']
        fvrt_count = json_data['favorite_count']
        rtwt_count = json_data['retweet_count']
        list_df.append({'tweet_id': tweet_id,
                        'favorite_count': fvrt_count,
                        'retweet_count': rtwt_count})

# create a pandas DataFrame using the list
df = pd.DataFrame(list_df, columns = ['tweet_id', 'favorite_count', 'retweet_count'])
df.head()
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking when we don't know what `tweet_json.txt` looks like, but if you're reading json data, pandas has a [read_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) function for that.

Comment: I am trying to save tweets to the json_txt file. But the result is an empty file. This code is reading stored data from the json_file. I cannot manage to fix it.  I do not understand why the file saved empty and as a result probably the error that I get trying to display the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment says you're trying to save to a file, but your code kind of says that you're trying to read from a file. Here are examples of how to do both:

### Writing to JSON

```
import json
import pandas as pd

content = {  # This just dummy data, in the form of a dictionary
    "tweet1": {
        "id": 1,
        "msg": "Yay, first!"
    },
    "tweet2": {
        "id": 2,
        "msg": "I'm always second :("
    }
}
# Write it to a file called "tweet_json.txt" in JSON
with open("tweet_json.txt", "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(content, json_file, indent=4)  # indent=4 is optional, it makes it easier to read
```

Note the `w` (as in **w**rite) in `open("tweet_json.txt", "w")`. You're using `r` (as in **r**ead), which doesn't give you permission to write anything. Also note the use of `json.dump()` rather than `json.load()`. We then get a file that looks like this:

```
$ cat tweet_json.txt
{
    "tweet1": {
        "id": 1,
        "msg": "Yay, first!"
    },
    "tweet2": {
        "id": 2,
        "msg": "I'm always second :("
    }
}
```

### Reading from JSON

Let's read the file that we just wrote, using pandas `read_json()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("tweet_json.txt")
print(df)
```

Output looks like this:

```
>>> df
          tweet1                tweet2
id             1                     2
msg  Yay, first!  I'm always second :(
```